# How to align label above the input?

Tags: html, css, scss-mixins

Attached is my code. I want to align the label above the item in a similar way as shown in the pic. Kindly help me out.

```css
form {
  background-color: white;
  width: 800px;
}


/* label,input{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
      }
    form input{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid white;
    } */

form button {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(9, 63, 228);
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="go">Where You Want to go</label>
  <input type="text" id="go" name="go" placeholder="Search your location" required minlength="6">
  <br>
  <label for="indate">Check-in</label>
  <input type="date" id="indate" name="indate" placeholder="Add Date" required><br>
  <label for="outdate">Check-out</label>
  <input type="date" id="outdate" name="outdate" placeholder="Add Date" required><br>
  <button>Explore Now</button>
</form>
```

I am not getting how to style it.[image: DESIGN FOR THE FORM]

Comment: What did you try, where did you get stuck? I'd suggest using CSS [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), or [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), for the layout. Have you tried either of them, or any other approach?

Comment: yes, I tried using flexbox but still didn't get the design wanted.I tried using flex on input and labels but still, there has been no success.

Comment: Great; can you edit the snippet I created from your code to show that attempt? That way we're able to explain how we address your problem, and where the errors in your own approach may have been. That way you learn something useful, and others visiting this question in future can learn something; as opposed to getting a black box of unexplained code from which it's difficult to learn.

Comment: I have edited my q. you can see my approach

Comment: are you using a `CSS` framework to help you with that ? `Bootstrap` for example ?

Comment: No nothing like that.Plain css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimum css

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

input, button {
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-container, button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="go">Where You Want to go</label>
    <input type="text" id="go" name="go" placeholder="Search your location" required minlength="6">
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="indate">Check-in</label>
    <input type="date" id="indate" name="indate" placeholder="Add Date" required>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="outdate">Check-out</label>
    <input type="date" id="outdate" name="outdate" placeholder="Add Date" required>
  </div>
  <button>Explore Now</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
form div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: max-content;
}

form div label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #333;
}

form div input {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px
  
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="go">Where You Want to go</label>
    <input type="text" id="go" name="go" placeholder="Search your location" required minlength="6">
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="indate">Check-in</label>
  <input type="date" id="indate" name="indate" placeholder="Add Date" required>
    </div>
  <div>
  <label for="outdate">Check-out</label>
  <input type="date" id="outdate" name="outdate" placeholder="Add Date" required>
    </div>
  <div>
  <button>Explore Now</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is as below, with explanatory comments in the code itself:

```css
/* simple means of forcing the browser to use the
   same algorithm to size elements, including the
   borders and padding in the declared size; also
   sets borders and padding to zero, all to reduce
   cross-browser differences: */
*,
::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  /* setting the size of the <form> on the inline-axis
     (effectively the axis on which text flows) to a
     size that contains the content of the element: */
  inline-size: fit-content;
  /* setting a 1em margin on the block axis (both start
     and end), the block axis is the axis on which
     blocks are laid out: */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* setting a margin of auto on the inline axis, centering
     the element on that axis: */
  margin-inline: auto;
  /* using Grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* setting a gap of zero on the block axis, and 0.5rem on
     the inline axis: */
  gap: 0 0.5rem;
  /* defining the size of four columns, the first three
     with the repeat function, which declares 3 columns
     each of a size of min-content; and the fourth of a size
     of 10rem: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content) 10rem;
  /* assigning the size of 2em to any rows created automatically: */
  grid-auto-rows: 2em;
}

label {
  /* defining the font-size: */
  font-size: 1.1em;
  /* placing the <label> elements on the first row: */
  grid-row: 1;
}

input {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  /* placing <input> elements on the second row: */
  grid-row: 2;
}

button {
  /* setting the <button> element to span 2 rows: */
  grid-row: span 2;
  /* and to fill all available space: */
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- other than removing the <br> elements, no
       changes were made to your HTML:  -->
  <label for="go">Where You Want to go</label>
  <input type="text" id="go" name="go" placeholder="Search your location" required minlength="6">
  <label for="indate">Check-in</label>
  <input type="date" id="indate" name="indate" placeholder="Add Date" required>
  <label for="outdate">Check-out</label>
  <input type="date" id="outdate" name="outdate" placeholder="Add Date" required>
  <button>Explore Now</button>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p3fyn40r/).

References:

- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows).
- [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add a few lines of CSS to nourhomsi's answer to make the whole form in one row.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

form div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: max-content;
}

form div label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #333;
}

form div input {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px
  
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="go">Where You Want to go</label>
    <input type="text" id="go" name="go" placeholder="Search your location" required minlength="6">
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="indate">Check-in</label>
  <input type="date" id="indate" name="indate" placeholder="Add Date" required>
    </div>
  <div>
  <label for="outdate">Check-out</label>
  <input type="date" id="outdate" name="outdate" placeholder="Add Date" required>
    </div>
  <div>
  <button>Explore Now</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
form div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  Justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width: max-content;
}
  form{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  gap:10px;
} 

form div label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #333;
}

form div input {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px
  
}
  form button {
  color: white;
  height:80%;
  background-color: rgb(9, 63, 228);
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="go">Where You Want to go</label>
    <input type="text" id="go" name="go" placeholder="Search your location" required minlength="6">
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="indate">Check-in</label>
  <input type="date" id="indate" name="indate" placeholder="Add Date" required>
    </div>
  <div>
  <label for="outdate">Check-out</label>
  <input type="date" id="outdate" name="outdate" placeholder="Add Date" required>
    </div>
  <div>
  <button>Explore Now</button>
    </div>
</form>
```